# why is queue empty for the file to be downloaded

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Below is the code that I have that downloads various URLS into each separate thread, I was in attempt to make some changes before I implement the thread pool but with this change the queue is coming to be empty and download is not beginning.

```
import Queue
import urllib2
import os
import utils as _fdUtils
import signal
import sys
import time
import threading

class ThreadedFetch(threading.Thread):
    """ docstring for ThreadedFetch
    """
    def __init__(self, queue,  out_queue):
        super(ThreadedFetch, self).__init__()
        self.queueItems = queue.get()
        self.__url = self.queueItems[0]
        self.__saveTo = self.queueItems[1]
        self.outQueue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        fileName = self.__url.split('/')[-1]
        path = os.path.join(DESKTOP_PATH, fileName)
        file_size = int(_fdUtils.getUrlSizeInBytes(self.__url))
        while not STOP_REQUEST.isSet():
            urlFh = urllib2.urlopen(self.__url)
            _log.info("Download: %s" , fileName)
            with open(path, 'wb') as fh:
                file_size_dl = 0
                block_sz = 8192
                while True:
                    buffer = urlFh.read(block_sz)
                    if not buffer:
                        break

                    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
                    fh.write(buffer)
                    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
                    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
                    sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % status)
                    time.sleep(.05)
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    if file_size_dl == file_size:
                        _log.info("Download Completed %s%% for file %s, saved to %s",
                                    file_size_dl * 100. / file_size, fileName, DESKTOP_PATH)
```

below is the main function that does the call and initiation.

```
def main(appName):

    args = _fdUtils.getParser()
    urls_saveTo = {}

    # spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance
    # each url will be downloaded concurrently
    for i in range(len(args.urls)):
        t = ThreadedFetch(queue, out_queue)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    try:
        for url in args.urls:
            urls_saveTo[url] = args.saveTo
        # urls_saveTo = {urls[0]: args.saveTo, urls[1]: args.saveTo, urls[2]: args.saveTo}
        # populate queue with data 
        for item, value in urls_saveTo.iteritems():
            queue.put([item, value])

        # wait on the queue until everything has been processed
        queue.join()
        print '*** Done'
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        lgr.critical('! Received keyboard interrupt, quitting threads.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the queue and then the first thread which immediately tries to fetch an item from the still empty queue.  The `ThreadedFetch.__init__()` method isn't run asynchronously, just the `run()` method when you call `start()` on a thread object.

Store the queue in the `__init__()` and move the `get()` into the `run()` method.  That way you can create all the threads and they are blocking in their own thread, giving you the chance to put items into the queue in the main thread.

```
class ThreadedFetch(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
        super(ThreadedFetch, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.outQueue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        url, save_to = self.queue.get()
        # ...
```

For this example the queue is unnecessary by the way as every thread gets exactly one item from the queue.  You could pass that item directly to the thread when creating the thread object:

```
class ThreadedFetch(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url, save_to, out_queue):
        super(ThreadedFetch, self).__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.save_to = save_to
        self.outQueue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        # ...
```

And when the `ThreadedFetch` class really just consists of the `__init__()` and `run()` method you may consider moving the `run()` method into a function and start that asynchronously.

```
def fetch(url, save_to, out_queue):
    # ...

# ...

def main():
    # ...

    thread = Thread(target=fetch, args=(url, save_to, out_queue))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```